# How to support devices 1.6 and up?

Tags: android, api

I've just started developing android apps and I am wondering about this right from the start. 
Apparently it doesn't matter if you work with API 13 (3.2), you can still support Android 1.6. Is that true?

For AdMob to work, I had to start working with API 13 and have set

```
target=android-13
```

Someone please clarify this or point me somewhere to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Manifest file you can put the min sdk version you want to support and your target sdk version, they could be different, to support 1.6 specify android:minSdkVersion="4" as follows

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll choose your answer because it's straightforward. For indepth explanation also thanks to @CommonsWare

Answer (score 3):

> Apparently it doesn't matter if you work with API 13 (3.2), you can still support Android 1.6. Is that true?

That depends on what you mean by "work with API 13".

Having a build target of API Level 13, as you mention later in your question, simply means that is the version of the Android SDK you are compiling against. You will be able to reference classes and methods that exist on API Level 13 (and earlier). Your app can still run on any version of Android you want.

However:

1. You cannot call methods that do not exist in API Level 13 when you are not running on an API Level 13 device (and likewise for API Level 12, 11, 10, etc.).
2. If you wish to support Android 1.x, you cannot even reference classes or methods that do not exist on the device from a class that gets loaded by the VM.

In either of those cases, you will get a `VerifyError`, and your app will go "boom".

There are strategies for conditionally using newer-API stuff that allow you to avoid trying to use that stuff on older-API devices. Or, just stick to older-API stuff in the first place, even though you won't get compiler assistance to let you know when you are accidentally using newer-API stuff, given that you are using the newer build target.

Or, contact AdMob support and figure out why they need that build target.

Comment: Thank you, this is EXACTLY the info I've been looking for.